# Block the app in mounted() until the user is authenticated using Amazon cognito and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

I authenticate the user with [Amazon Cognito](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-vuex-module) in a Vue.js app with the following code:

```
export default new Vue({
    mounted() {
    store.dispatch('authenticateUser', { email: 'username', password: 'password' }).then(() => {
        if (store.state.cognito.authenticated) {
        // Add authentication token to each request
        axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
            const response = await store.dispatch('getUserSession');
            if (response && response.accessToken && response.accessToken.jwtToken) {
            config.headers.AccessToken = response.accessToken.jwtToken;
            }
            return config;
        });
        } else {
        this.flashError('AWS user is not authenticated.');
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        this.flashError(`AWS authentication error: ${err.message}`);
    });
    },
}).$mount('#app');
```

First I start async **authenticateUser** action and when it is completed I set up **axios** in a way all the **axios** requests automatically send the authentication info to the server.

The only thing I did not figure out yet is to how to make all the **axios** requests in the app wait for async authentication completed. (For example, the main app page can fire **axios** request to fill its data when the async authentication is still in progress, so there should be some mechanism to make it wait).

In other languages (like C++ or C#, for example) there are two alternatives: 1. block the app in mounted() until authentication is completed. 2. make all the requests wait the completion event.

what about JavaScript?

To implement the 1-st scenario I tried

```
await store.dispatch('authenticateUser', { email: 'username', password: 'password' }).then(() => {
```

but this does not compile.

**EDIT1:** Is store.dispatch really asynchronous?

**EDIT2:** I tried to add 'async' to mounted(). Is it a step to a right direction?

```
async mounted() {
  await store.dispatch('authenticateUser', { email: 'username', password: 'password' }).then(() => {
  ....
},
```

Comment: i had answered your last question, here i see that the needs are changed and i understood that you want that your app would be rendered after the authentification is completed?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim At first, yes. Now I need the app to work with hardcoded credentials. Partially the app can be rendered (probably it can show some progress indicator), but all the API call should be made after the authentication is complete. see EDIT2, is it a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have an app with some content and you want to allow only the authenticated users to access that else you will redirect the wrong user to another page, i suggest to do it as follow

```
   import Vue from 'vue';
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
    import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
    import Vuex from 'vuex';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
    import store from './index'
    Vue.use(Vuetify);
    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    Vue.use(Vuex);
    Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

     var myapp=null;

  store.dispatch('authenticateUser', { email: 'username', password: 'password' }).then(() => {
    if (store.state.cognito.authenticated) {
    // Add authentication token to each request
    axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
        const response = await store.dispatch('getUserSession');
        if (response && response.accessToken && response.accessToken.jwtToken) {
        config.headers.AccessToken = response.accessToken.jwtToken;
         myapp=new Vue({}).$mount('#app');//the right app
        }
        return config;
    });
    } else {
    this.flashError('AWS user is not authenticated.');
     myapp=new Vue({}).$mount('#app');//app that contains warnings
    }
}).catch((err) => {
    this.flashError(`AWS authentication error: ${err.message}`);
    myapp=new Vue({}).$mount('#app');//app that contains warnings
});
```

so if the response is ok you will create a `Vue` instance with the right content

```
 myapp=new Vue({}).$mount('#app');
```

else redirect that user to app that contains warnings